# How can I inject javascript into a .exe that is electron based?

Tags: javascript

When I start the Twitch Desktop Client (The one I want the javascript to run on) I open up the Chrome Console and paste js into the console and execute it. Done.

My problem here is that every time the Desktop Client refreshes / closes, the js gets removed so I keep having to paste the js in the console every time I open / refresh the client.

I want to automate this process somehow, someway.

**EDIT**
This Desktop Client is not a Web Browser. You **cannot** install extentions like tamper-monkey etc.

This is literally just a Desktop Client with a Chrome Console.
I don't know too much about this subject like if the client is Electron based.

**EDIT2**
This Client is Web Browser based I think, that's my guess on why it has the chrome devtools console.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? Because this is not how chrome has been designed to be used. You might however find other tools that have been design for your purpose. (like [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) or [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer))

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by “C++ code injecting javascript code”. The reason there is a “chrome” like console in the executable is because the executable is built with a Chromium browser bundled in. One of the frameworks that use this is ElectronJS

Comment: @Olian04 I could use a different language not just C++ but I mean literally doing the same thing as pasting code into the chrome console except automated

Comment: But why? Why do you want to run code in the chrome devtools console?

Comment: @Olian04 edited the post so it's more clear

Comment: So you talk about an application based on Electron, for which you want a custom script to be executed every time you launch this application?

Comment: @t.niese I guess so.

Comment: You can think about directly patching the source code. Electron apps normally have a `asar` file somewhere, which is similar to a `zip` or `tar` file, containing everything. You can extract that, patch the source, and repack it.

Comment: What "Desktop Client" is it? What's the name of the program?

Comment: @t.niese it is Electron based. It has blob_storage and stuff similar to what Discord has.
I can't seem to find any type of core.asar though.

Comment: @Olian04 It's Twitch's Desktop Client, based on Electron I am presuming.

Comment: If its electron based, then you might be able to use [`electron-inject`](https://github.com/tintinweb/electron-inject)

Comment: @t.niese I found a asar.asar file

Comment: @Olian04 that only enables the dev console, which I already have access to.

Comment: Well then extract the asar file dig through the source and find a place at which you can hook into. Or check the source of the `electron-inject` and see if you can extend that script to not only open the dev console but to inject code (which is most likely possible). You now have two hints based on which you now can do further research yourself. And no I don't know how you can exactly solve the task, I would also need to do some further research.

Comment: @t.niese will do!